# wine for windows games

Tags: wine

I have wine 1.3 and playonlinux, winetricks and q4 that gui for wine and have tried many things but I am not able to run san andreas and mostwanted.

The games both start but they appear as coloured blocks. The start screen is flashing black and white and winedb rates the games as platinum and gold respectively. what do I do?? I have tried other windows soft wares on wine the work fine...

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is marked for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Sounds suspiciously like you're on an Intel graphics chipset. The open source driver doesn't include S3 Texture Compression for patent reasons. S3TC is used in almost all serious 3D applications, including games. Not having it tends to result in a lot of fail.

I asked about this a while back and got an answer that worked for me:

- [Is there an easy way to enable S3TC on Intel graphics?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56379/is-there-an-easy-way-to-enable-s3tc-on-intel-graphics)

Comment: well well you are so right... intel.... but download the driconfiguration app from the app store and set the S3TC setting to yes!! the games will start working... but my most wanted does not play the videos and sound tracks the engine sounds and all are perfect.

Answer (score -1):

Concerning the soundtracks: are they MP3s? I only ask because due to licensing issues Wine does not have mp3 support and the workarounds do not work. Some programs, like VLC have built in mp3 support and can play mp3s under wine, but games that use mp3s will not play them.

Your lucky the game is not giving you an error about that, some games will not even run on wine until you delete it's sound files. Converting to OGG works for some games, however due to licensing issues with FFMPEG, you will not be able to use Linux to convert them. I had to use windows on my duel boot to convert the audio so I could go back to linux and use the  music in Wine.