# Trying to install Neverwinter Nights again, and having yet another different failure

Tags: games, 16.04, segmentation-fault

So, as the title says, I'm trying to install NWN again. It went awry a while back in a Kubuntu VM ( as noted here: [Neverwinter Nights hangs at startup in my Kubuntu 14.10 VMWare Guest](https://askubuntu.com/questions/553404/neverwinter-nights-hangs-at-startup-in-my-kubuntu-14-10-vmware-guest)), and I got some help, but..now I'm having a completely different problem.

I did the installation from scratch on a Xenial + MATE box, unzipping all my archives as before, and I couldn't believe my luck! The game launched, with video and everything! I didn't have sound, but nixing its built-in SDL and installing libSDL1.2:i386 got that going. I haven't tested to see if it's playing nicely with my system mixer, but I was too excited to worry about that. That is..until I tried to open the sound menu to mute the music and..segmentation fault.

Okay. I'll just take care of that in the config file later. How about graphics options? Oh, hey, that menu loads. Maybe it's a sound issue. How about advanced graphics..segmentation fault.

Okay. Let's try connecting to a world. Multiplayer looks good. Wait for the timeout as is customary..join internet game..segmentation fault.

Okay. What about single player? New game, and..weird purple screen telling me that the UI map wasn't found and with no way out. Send sigterm from another session, get a prompt for whether or not I really want to quit, say yes, and..segmentation fault.

I don't even..what? I'm assuming I'm missing a dependency or something, but all the package names have changed since any tutorials were written, and running strace doesn't appear to point to any files that weren't found.

Thoughts/advice? =/

Answer (score 1):

Rawr. I feel like an idiot. So, on the off chance that someone in the future makes the same mistake I did, here's what it was:

I skipped the XP1.zip and XP2.zip files in the installation process. The correct sequence of zips that got me going was:

```
Data_Shared.zip (shared files for base game)
Data_Linux.zip (Linux-specific files for base game)
XP1.zip (base files for Shadows of Undretide)
nwclientgold.tar.gz (binaries/Linux-specific files for SoU)
XP2.zip (base files for Hordes of the Underdark)
nwclienthotu.tar.gz (binaries/Linux-specific files for HotU)
English_linuxclient169_xp2.tar.gz (update to latest version)
```

I sincerely hope I can take it from here. Thanks to anyone who looked at this.